# RFHutilc with json ccdt files

Tags: ibm-mq

How to use Json format ccdt files on RFHUtil client utility?
Does RFHutil client utility support json files?
i am using json file to connect to Remote Queue manger with SSL enabled.
can anyone suggest?

Comment: As long as you are at a version of MQ that supports json ccdt and rfhutil supports normal binary CCDT, there is no reason it will not work with json ccdt.

Comment: It is not the MQ client application that needs to support JSON CCDT files but rather the underlying installed MQ Client.  The IBM MQ Client needs to be at v9.2 or higher to support JSON CCDT files.

Comment: When you tried it, did you get an error suggesting that it did not work?

Comment: I have more than one version of mq server installed. which will used by rfhutilc as underlying mq client? Or does rfhutilc doesn't use mq server and indeed there should be a mq client it's using .If rfhutilc can work with only mq client installed,can we have more than 1 version of mq installed on a same machine